# Azure Active directory Login Getting Claims want to add more claims from Local DB

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-mvc

So on the SignIn Method

```
  public IActionResult SignIn()
        {
           if (_unitOfWork.User.IsAuth(HttpContext) == true)
            {
                var _userCurrentObject = _unitOfWork.User.GetCurrentUserObject(HttpContext);
                var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                new Claim("UserType",   _userCurrentObject.UserType),
           };
                var appIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims);
                HttpContext.User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                User.AddIdentity(appIdentity);
                User.Claims.Append(new Claim("Wow", "value-x"));
                var zz = User;// i can see the Claim which i Add here but in other Action not able to see those Claims 
         
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {

                return RedirectToAction("AccessDenied", "Home");
            }


    }
```

Tying to access those claims in other controllers like this

```
  string UserType = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "UserType")?.Value;
```

Till here everything working fine but when I app trying to access user in other action not able to see custom claims which I add Like "Usertype"

Am I missing something?

Comment: Hi Zcoder, please improve the question a luttle bit. As per my undertanding, you are trying to add claims to a given user when he tries to signin in your app. But I dont understand how you could possibilly access those values in another controller?

Comment: Like this it working in sign Method showing new claims.. but not working any other controller after sign in showing null value   string UserType = User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "UserType")?.Value;

Comment: Claims can be persisted either on the database or in a jwt token, it seems to me that you are not persisting those values.

Comment: Check [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0), and try to use `HttpContext.SignInAsync` method to set the claims. Besides, you could also try to use session or cache to store the claims, then, if you want to use it, you can get them  from the session or cache. Besides, if you are using Asp.net Core Identity, you can also use [UserManager to add  the specified claim to the user](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/claim-based-and-policy-based-authorization-with-asp-net-core-2-1/), or store the claims in the claims tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save User claims and use them using DI in an elegant way using `IMemoryCache`. The code goes like below:

**Startup.cs:**

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<IPrincipal>(
            provider => provider.GetService<IHttpContextAccessor>().HttpContext.User);
        services.AddTransient<IClaimsTransformation, ClaimsTransformer>();
        services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

    }
```

**ClaimsTransformer.cs:**

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public ClaimsTransformer(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
    {
        var cacheKey = principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

        if (_cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out List<Claim> claims)
        {
            ((ClaimsIdentity)principal.Identity).AddClaims(claims);
        }
        else
        {
            claims = new List<Claim>();          

            // call to database to get more claims based on user id ClaimsIdentity.Name

            _cache.Set(cacheKey, claims);
        }

        return principal;
    }
}
```

I would also recommend you to read about `IMemoryCache` here: [Cache in-memory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/memory?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
        public const string SessionKeyByPassUserName = "_LoggedIn_ByPassUserName";

        //public ClaimsTransformer(D2CContext context)
        public ClaimsTransformer(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
        {
            _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        }
        public Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            var identity = principal.Identities.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsAuthenticated);
            if (identity == null) return Task.FromResult(principal);

            var userEmail = identity?.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "preferred_username")?.Value;
            var userObj = _unitOfWork.TblUserSecurity.GetEmail(userEmail);
            var domainUserName = userObj?.UserName;

            //checking if bypass user cookie exists, setting it to domainUserName
            IHttpContextAccessor _accessor = new HttpContextAccessor();
            //if (_accessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["bypassUser"] != null)
            //{
            //    domainUserName = _accessor.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["bypassUser"];
            //}

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(domainUserName)) return Task.FromResult(principal);

            var existingClaims = identity.Claims;
            var claims = new List<Claim>();

            claims.AddRange(existingClaims);
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(identity.FindFirst("LoggedInUserName")?.Value))
                claims.Add(new Claim("LoggedInUserName", userObj.UserType));
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserType", userObj.UserType ));
            claims.Add(new Claim("IsViewCaseManager", userObj.IsViewCaseManager != null ? userObj.IsViewCaseManager.ToString() : "False"));
            claims.Add(new Claim("IsDefaultCaseManager", userObj.IsDefaultCaseManager != null ? userObj.IsDefaultCaseManager.ToString() : "False"));
            claims.Add(new Claim("UserName", userObj.UserName));
       
   
            //   if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Role)?.Value))
            //      claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, userObj.Role.RoleName));

            var newClaimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "Kerberos", "", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role");

            var newClaimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(newClaimsIdentity);

            return Task.FromResult(new ClaimsPrincipal(newClaimsPrincipal));
        }
    }
}
```

Middleware

```
Service.AddTrasnsient<IClaimsTransformation,ClaimsTransformer >();
```

Comment: This is how we can also achieve